# Is anybody in ROS community using PySide?

Tags: ros, python, pyqt, gui, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If not, what about PyQt?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9096/is-anybody-in-ros-community-using-pyside?/) by [Alex Bravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27/alex-bravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 901 on 2011-02-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know of either right now; presumably because everything is wxwidgets and associated wxpython/swig stuff.   Plans are to move to Qt as you may know, but nothing has yet.  Availability on Ubuntu will be important in the long run.  [edited] looks like the commenters below have some good info.

---

Originally posted by [Straszheim](https://answers.ros.org/users/44/straszheim/) with karma: 426 on 2011-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alex Bravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27/alex-bravo/) on 2011-02-16**:
There are Lucid and Maverick binaries here: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/PySide_Binaries_Linux

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-02-16**:
There is a python-pyside package in Maverick and Natty, but none for Lucid. We would need a Lucid version to use it in any supported Diamondback packages. That could be handled specially in rosdep, but it's a pain.

**Comment by [Alex Bravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27/alex-bravo/) on 2011-02-16**:
PyQt as it has GPL licence + commercial (paying) license. PySide is LGPL, so it's preferred. PySide is approaching 1.0 release (they are now on beta 5).